# Comprobaciones Alert Dialog Android

Tags: android, alertdialog

Estoy intentando hacer unas comprobaciones dentro de un `alertdialog` para ver si se cumplen unas condiciones y dejar al usuario seguir con el proceso. Pero cuando el usuario le da al botón de descargar (PositiveButton) hace las comprobaciones y se sale del `alertdialog` se cumplan o no, cuando lo que yo quiero es que sino cumple alguna condición no se cierre el `alertdialog`.

El `alertdialog` es el siguiente:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y el código del `alertdialog` es:

```
dialog.setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.calendar_dialog_info));
dialog.setView(layout);
dialog.setCancelable(false);

dialog.setPositiveButton(getResources().getString(R.string.download), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

        KeyValueArrayAdapter.KeyValue sel = (KeyValueArrayAdapter.KeyValue) spinner_cal.getSelectedItem();

        String cuentaSel = sel.value;
        long idsel = Long.parseLong(sel.key);

        if(idsel != -1) { 
            if (Utiles.conexionDisponible(getApplicationContext())) {
                String tipo = Constants.CALENDARIO_ALUMNO;//TODO saber que tipo hay que descargar
                //pasar id calendario y tipo de calendario
                ObtenerCalendario obtenerTask = new ObtenerCalendario( tipo, idsel);
                obtenerTask.execute();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getResources().getString(R.string.no_conex), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            dialog.cancel();
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(PantallaPersonalActivity.this, "No se ha seleccionado nada " , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
});
dialog.setNegativeButton(getResources().getString(R.string.cancel), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
        // Cancelar
        dialog.cancel();
    }
});

dialog.show();
```

**EDITADO**:

El **comportamiento esperado** es que cuando se pulse al botón de descargar compruebe si se ha seleccionado un calendario, si se ha seleccionado cerrar el `alertdialog` y llamar a un `AsyncTask`, pero si no se ha seleccionado nada quiero que no se cierre el `alertdialog` y muestre ya sea por un `Toast`, `SnackBar` o en el mismo `alertdialog` que seleccione un calendario.

Comment: ¿Cuál es el comportamiento esperado? ¿Después de dar clic en 'descargar' que debe hacer, carga un _progressBar_, muestra otro _Dialog_, abre una nueva _activity_, muestra un _Toast_, que debe de hacer?

Comment: @x4mp73r editado con el comportamiento esperado

Comment: echale un vistazo a este link  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14995429/dialog-box-with-radio-button-and-validate-button

Comment: Muchas gracias @Maguz probaré lo que me dices

Comment: ¿Y si mueves el  `dialog.cancel();` y lo pones después de tu último `else ` ?

Comment: @x4mp73r he probado a ponerlo después del último else y no funciona, voy a probar con lo de Maguz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Después de echarle un vistazo al consejo de @Maguz he dado con una solución a lo que quería hacer, he optado por crear un `alertdialog` con selección única de items (Radios) con la función `setSingleChoiceItems()` quedando el código de la siguiente forma:

```
final KeyValueArrayAdapter calendarios = CalendarUtils.obtenerCalendars(PantallaPersonalActivity.this);

AlertDialog alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
    .setTitle(R.string.calendar_dialog_info)
    .setCancelable(false)
    .setSingleChoiceItems(calendarios.getEntries(), -1, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

            String id = calendarios.getEntryValue(which);
            String nombre = calendarios.getEntry(which);

            long idsel = Long.parseLong(id);

            Log.i("calendario","cuenta sel: '" + nombre+ "' id: '"+ idsel+"'");

            if (Utiles.conexionDisponible(getApplicationContext())) {
                String tipo = Constants.CALENDARIO_ALUMNO;//TODO saber que tipo hay que descargar

                //pasar id calendario y tipo de calendario
                ObtenerCalendario obtenerTask = new ObtenerCalendario( tipo, idsel);
                obtenerTask.execute();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getResources().getString(R.string.no_conex), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    })
//  .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
//
//      @Override
//      public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

//      }
//  })
    .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    }).create();

    alert.show();
```

Captura de como queda el `alertdialog` con este código:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

De esta forma obligo al usuario a que seleccione un calendario o que cancele la acción, evitando comprobar que no ha seleccionado ningún calendario, ya que cuando seleccione uno continuará con el proceso de descarga del calendario.